# Thread-safe access to class members

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++03

Is accessing two different class members of the same object from two different POSIX threads at the same time considered to be thread-safe in C++ 03?

Comment: In C++ 03 there was no standard memory model, so it is not possible to answer this question from the point of the C++ standard.

Comment: Since they are different memory locations though it should be thread safe by all means regardless the memory/consistency model, that is unless the threads are trying to synchronise on these members.

Comment: @computador7 we needed a memory model in C++ specifically because what you said is not true - if a compiler doesn't know that an environment is multithreaded, it will do many kinds of optimizations that often involve touching memory locations they should not in a multithreaded environment. That said, `-pthread` should at least partially fix that problem.

Comment: What kind of optimizations are you refering to? First of all if you access different memory locations from different threads you do not get race conditions. Now if the threads need to see the other thread updates in the correct order this is where the memory model specification comes in! Next I don't think there are memory locations that the compiler should not touch in a multithreaded environment and even if there were any I can't see how those optimizations you are refering to would do so anyway! Could you elaborate more?

Comment: -pthread links the pthread library and some macros for reentrancy and thread local storage I don't see how it relates to this.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** (with a little voice of "yes")

From the point of view of the C++03 standard, no such thing as threads exists, so there exist no conditions whatsoever under which the standard would consider anything involving concurrency as "safe".

While this is often no problem (with a little care and proper synchronization primitives that are outside the scope of C++, it will "work anyway"), there are a few things to be aware of, among these:

- `errno` (and other structures) might not be thread-local. The `-pthread` command line option mostly addresses this.
- Class members may alias each other through references, pointers, or unions, so mutating *different* members might indeed mutate *the same* member concurrently
- Without memory model, the compiler is allowed to (and will!) reorder loads and stores, which means that for example the "obvious" way of communicating by first writing a piece of data, and then setting a "data is ready" flag may not work as expected.
- Under Windows, there exist some not-immediately-obvious static-dynamic CRT issues in presence of threading when your program loads DLLs. Be sure all components do *"the same thing"* (whatever it is).
- Also, some old versions of the CRT may leak a few hundred bytes of memory per thread (usually not an issue).
- Immutable objects are inherently thread-safe, as is read-only access from several threads.